# Passing selected row data to next View Controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am new to Swift Programming and I am having problems. So what I want to do is when the user selects the row in a table then I want to grab the selected row's title and then pass it to the next View Controller. Here is my code for the First View Controller:

```
let senderArray = ["Sogyal","Ram"]
let messageArray = ["Hello","What's up?"]

cell.senderName.text = senderArray[indexPath.row]
cell.senderMessage.text = messageArray[indexPath.row]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    newIndex = indexPath.row

    let selectedMessage = messageArray[indexPath.row]

    let composeVC = ComposeMessageVC()
    composeVC.usernameLbl = selectedMessage

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToComposeM", sender: self)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` if you are using a segue. So change your `didSelectRowAt` to this:

```
newIndex = indexPath.row

let selectedMessage = messageArray[indexPath.row]

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToComposeM", sender: selectedMessage)
```

Then override `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ComposeMessageVC {
        vc.usernameLbl = sender as! String
    }
}
```

Your approach did not work because you are creating a new VC yourself, which is a different one from the one that is actually presented.

Comment: where should i use the override func?

Comment: In your VC, alongside other funcs. @SogyalThundupSherpa

Comment: i am getting an error in the                                                                                        if let vc = sender.destination as? ComposeMessageVC {
        vc.usernameLbl = sender as! String
    }

Comment: @SogyalThundupSherpa oops! It should have been `segue.destination`.

Comment: Will it be a UILabel ? not a string? as i am getting an error when it is a label  Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10c51e168) to 'UILabel' (0x10a434d68).

Comment: @SogyalThundupSherpa Oh so `vc.usernameLbl` is a `UILabel`? Then you need to add another variable in ComposeMessageVC to receive the data. You then set the label's text to that variable in the VC's viewDidLoad.

Comment: i got an error Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10c51e168) to 'UILabel' (0x10a434d68)

Comment: @SogyalThundupSherpa If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @SogyalThundupSherpa this is not an on topic question for stack overflow, try searching on google.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    ...
    let destination = YourViewController()
    destination.usernameLbl = selectedMessage
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    ...
}
```