# Swift, pass data from dynamic cell row selection to popover view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, popover

My question is if it is possible to pass data from a tableview cell that is selected to other view controller

The table view in the first controller uses a prototype cell

[image: First view controller tableview cell prototype]

The second view controller has 3 other labels as shown here

[image: Secon viewController preview]

I tried what is described here: [passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466713/passing-selected-row-data-to-next-view-controller-swift-3) but it didn't work and gave me the error "Placeholder for UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegueTemplate" which I understand from reading [this old thread top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236621/what-does-the-couldnt-compile-connection-error-mean) that is because I am using a prototype cell and its dynamic

what I want is that every time an user selects a row, the second view controller is filled with this relation

String 1 → String 4

String 2 → String 5

String 3 → String 6

So far I have tried a couple things like:

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:  "secondVC") as! CalculadoraViewController
            present(vc, animated: true)
            let string4 = string4array[indexPath[1]]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "secVC", sender: string4)            
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? CalculadoraViewController {
            vc.string4.text = (sender as! String)
        }
    }
```

The popover view controller code:

```
class CalculadoraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var string4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var string5: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you pass data

```
class CalculadoraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var montoUSD: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var montoCRC: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var prVenta: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prCompra: UILabel!
    var prVentaText:String!
    var prCompraText:String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        prVenta.text = prVentaText
        prCompra.text = prCompraText


        montoUSD.placeholder = montoCRC.text
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:  "calculadora") as! CalculadoraViewController

        vc.prCompraText = String(precioCompra[indexPath.row])
        vc.prVentaText =  String(precioVenta[indexPath.row])

    present(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: hi, I tried that, the problem is that the "if" is giving me this error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Float'". Thanks

Comment: Now I get this "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: can you share demo project to test ?

Comment: where you are facing this problem ? which controller ?

Comment: sent you pull request as well ... hope it helps ... Happy coding =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214515/discussion-between-allanguzmanf-and-jawadali).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform segue if you are presenting the `View-Controller`:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "secondVC") as! CalculadoraViewController
    vc.string4.text = string4array[indexPath.row]
    present(vc, animated: true)         
}
```

Comment: ok I understand that for me to display the second view controller I don't need the segue, but the question is how to pass data from the selected table view cell to the second view controller

Comment: It's already given in the answer. `vc.string4.text = "Whatever data you need to pass"`